# A beginner trying to run a single line of output with end=' ' in Python but faces SyntaxError

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a pure beginner who just started learning about Python 2 days ago and I really have no idea where to find the answer to this.

I am trying to run this code with a single line output:

```
from itertools import groupby

for k, c in groupby(str(input())):
    print(len(list(c)), int(k), end=' ')
```

but am faced with Error saying:

```
  File "Solution.py", line 6
    print(len(list(c)), int(k), end=' ')
                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax (expected ')')
```

I tried googling for answer but seems like everyone has no issue with using ***end=' '***

Feeling really stuck now that I can't progress to the next level. Please help me find out what is wrong, thank you sooo much!

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or Python 3? You say Python 2 in the text, but have the `python-3.x` tag. The error would happen in Python 2.

Comment: Python 2 is obsolete. If you're a beginner, you should use Python 3.

Comment: It could be very helpful - if you include some inputs here and what's your expect outputs - if it works.

Answer (score 0):

You are using python 2.X (better if you use python 3). You can either import the print function from Python 3 using the `__future__` module

```
from __future__ import print_function
from itertools import groupby

for k, c in groupby(str(input())):
    print(len(list(c)), int(k), end=' ')
```